# OWL - associate transitive child with great-parent

Tags: owl, reasoning, shacl, allegrograph

I would like to simplify my SHACL definitions by reversing the relations between shapes, properties and groups.

A typical `NodeShape` looks like this. Two properties in a group:

```
<>
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:property
  [
    sh:name "Property 1" ;
    sh:order 1 ;
    sh:group <#Group> ;
  ] ,
  [
    sh:name "Property 2" ;
    sh:order 2 ;
    sh:group <#Group> ;
  ] ;
.
```

It becomes a little unwieldy when there are multiple groups and many properties because all of them are tangled in the `sh:property` list of objects.

What I would like to achieve is to revers the relations a little using OWL rules so that I could type the RDF differently, but retain the equivalence with the above using reasoning.

```
<>
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  ex:group <#Group> ;
.

<#Property1>
  sh:name "Property 1" ;
  sh:order 1 ;
.

<#Property2>
  sh:name "Property 2" ;
  sh:order 2 ;
.

<#Group>
  ex:property <#Property1>, <#Property2>
.
```

Is there a way to define `ex:group` and `ex:property` to infer the triples from first snippet?